# Writing a for loop in Objective C way

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a doubts in writing a for loop in Objective C way. I can do the same loop in traditional C for loop, However I am trying to learn Objective C. Here is my question.
listdata is a mutable array holding objects of ofi_vc_modal_ab_user_info objects, I want to compare each email of list data with email until list data count and find its position and if found I want to delete the object from list data.

```
    for (ofi_vc_modal_ab_user_info *loc_obj in listData)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(loc_obj->email, email) == 0) {
           // What need to do here.
        }
    }
```

How to proceed here... thanks for your helps :)

Comment: I know you already have an accepted answer, but you should look at the 'enumerate... with block' methods now available for most collection objects. Apple tells us at WWDC each year these result in much less code and area also much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BOOL foundObject = NO; 
ofi_vc_modal_ab_user_info *loc_found_obj = nil; 
for (ofi_vc_modal_ab_user_info *loc_obj in listData)
{
    if (strcasecmp(loc_obj->email, email) == 0) {
       // Set your flag here
       loc_found_obj = loc_obj;
        foundObject = YES;
        break;
    }
}
if(foundObject) {
// Do your stuffs as object is found
// Your found object is in loc_found_obj
 [listData removeObject:loc_found_obj];
}
```

I hope below code explains what you want. Please explain bit more if you need more help.

EDIT : If you are using `NSMutableArray` then you do not need index of the object. you can directly delete object as mentioned in my edited code.

Comment: BornCoder How do I delete the object at index here?

Comment: Ya its working thanks, then how justin is saying its an error, I saw similar kind of approach in one of apple documentation.

Comment: Do you mean it is giving error? It should not be giving any error. Please explain what kind of error it is giving.

Comment: As per Justin comment pls check his comment, in my case its working fine.

Comment: Not good approach You cant remove object from `listData` when you're doing `for (ofi_vc_modal_ab_user_info *loc_obj in listData)` ... **ERROR**

Answer (score 6):

you can just use C's `for`.

in fact, it's an error to mutate the collection you iterate over when using `for (e in collection)`.

Comment: Justin I have done like Born and Prince suggested, it looks working for my case.

Comment: @user1587011 if BornCoder's approach works for you, feel free to accept BornCoder's answer.